# Multiple publisher to event grid

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

Does a single event grid handle events from multiple IoT hubs? We have multiple IoT hub and each emits event and we are looking to handle that event and we end up having an event grid. However, we are puzzled how to send events from multiple IoT hubs to a single event grid? Is this possible or we will end up having an event grid for each IoT hub?

Comment: You do not get to manage or create an event grid. Yes, you will get many event grid topics and subscriptions but that's the nature of the beast, so to speak. What are you worried about?

Comment: Thanks, Peter for a quick response, we want all our IoT hub to send events to only one event grid. Currently, we are able to send an event from one IoT hub to the event grid.

Comment: That is odd. Can you clarify what kind of events you are publishing and how you did set it up?

Comment: Is it possible to have only on event grid in the architecture or we should have an event grid for each IoT hub to track the device events? We are publishing device created, deleted, enabled and disabled.

Comment: I think the biggest thing in our communication here is the use of the word 'event grid'. You do *not* have to create any event grid. Azure already takes care of that. You will just have to create an event subscription to get the events of all the devices attached to the iot hub as shown here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-how-to-order-connection-state-events#configure-subscription-for-iot-hub-events

Comment: Ok, my wording might be confusing you. So, each IoT hub will have its own event subscription to post the event or multiple IoT hub can post events to single event subscriptions.

Comment: Ah, now I understand it. Thanks for the explanation. But, AFAIK you cannot reuse a subscription. You can, of course, use the same endpoint for all the subscriptions so all the events will be processed by the same endpoint.

Comment: Thanks Peter, this is what I wanted to know.